# Hazelcast: IMap as singleton and how to configure TTL

Tags: hazelcast

We're currently getting an hazelcast `IMap` each time a request is incoming.

Sample code:

```java
@GetMapping("/tipus-adreca")
public List<TipusAdrecaDTO> getTipusAdreca(){
    IMap<String, String> hzMap = hzInstance.getMap(HesConstants.SISTEMA_TELECOMUNICACIONS);
    //Do something
}
```

I'm running in my mind if it's too eager.

Is there any best practice in order to obtain `IMap`? I mean, Could I get `IMap` as a `@Bean`?

By other side... Is there any way to configure TTL of each `IMap`?hazelcast

Answer (score 0):

> By other side... Is there any way to configure TTL of each IMap?hazelcast

You can't define a TTL for an IMap, but you can for the entries of the IMap.

Answer (score 0):

You should most certainly not be doing hz.getMap for every cluster access request. Its an expensive operation, so look to reuse the IMap instance instead of getting from the cluster.